# how to sort data based on dateTime using firebase and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

this is my current json response.. what i wanted to do is to sort this based on time.

```
router.get('/getmessage/:uuid',function(req, res){
    chatID = req.params.uuid;

    var chat = database.ref('chats/'+ chatID);
    id = _.split(chatID, '_', 2);
    chat.once('value', function(snapshot){
        dataSet = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childsnapshot){

            dataSet.push({
                child: childsnapshot
            })
        })
        newDataSet = dataSet.sort(function(a,b){

            return a.child.val().time - b.child.val().time;
        })
        res.json(newDataSet);
    })
});
```

this is my script. i tried using .sort but when i tried to `console.log(a.child.val().time - b.child.val().time)` it returns NaN and still i got the current result..
this is the result that i wanted to get.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#sort` with `string#localeCompare`.

```js
var data = [{child:{time:'2018-02-21 16:41:30'}}, {child:{time:'2018-02-21 16:30:21'}}];
data.sort((a,b) => a.child.time.localeCompare(b.child.time));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks it works.. but can you tell me what is the diff of using .localeCompare to - which is i commonly saw when i tried searching on how to sort.

Comment: The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.